# Field Name including a period gives me error (using brackets)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I put together an Access Database for a department. They've been using it frequently for the past few months with no hiccups.

However, they changed one of the field names of a linked Excel File, which forces me to go into Access and update the query a bit.

The field name has gone from "PacU" to "Mr. Cooper"

Original:

```
SELECT Round(BidTemplate.[PacU],6) AS PacU
```

New:

```
SELECT Round(BidTemplate.[Mr. Cooper],6) AS [Mr. Cooper]
```

I am receing an error as follows "Invalid bracketing of the name 'BidTeample.[Mr.Cooper]'.

I'm sure the issue is driven off of the period that is now included in the field. But shouldn't the brackets take care of this?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field names cannot contain a period.

From the [MS Access Documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-for-naming-fields-controls-and-objects-120c27fa-7ae1-4182-9baa-dbd183179cc3):

> Names of fields, controls, and objects in Microsoft Access desktop databases:
>
> - Can be up to 64 characters long.
> - Can include any combination of letters, numbers, spaces, and special characters **except a period (.)**, an exclamation point (!), an
>     accent grave (`), and brackets ([ ]).
> - Can't begin with leading spaces.
> - Can't include control characters (ASCII values 0 through 31).
> - Can't include a double quotation mark (") in table, view, or stored procedure names in a Microsoft Access project.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll have to explain this to them and remove the period (.) from the field name. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

remove extra space

```
SELECT Round(BidTemplate.[Mr Cooper],6) AS [Mr Cooper]
```

Comment: The new field name has a space, contradicting my original statement. I have now edited the post appropriately. Thank you for the reply!